# Raspberry pi controlled automated drone

Tags: python

I have to make an indoor drone(no GPS). The input to the drone will be the starting coordinates and the ending coordinates. I have an indoor map. How do I make this? The raspberry will be onboard the drone. I have tried Wifi positioning since there are a lot of routers but can't get the desired accuracy. I also tried using accelerometer to measure distance(Kalman filter and all) but the distance is not measured accurately. It should be using python 2.x
I am going to use dijkstra or A* algorithm to route. I marked the nodes on the map to cover all locations that I have to go.

Comment: Maybe you can try to use distance measurement (between drone and walls - IR or supersonic), or kind of LIDAR system?

Comment: This is too broad for the site and it's not clear that anything about it is actually directly related to Raspberry Pi. (Seems like a navigation and control problem in general.)